# How to change a browsed page's <input>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm jQuery beginner.
I'm trying to modify the source code of a page I'm browsing, using Firefox plus Greasemonkey.

How can I modify:

```
<input id="HiddenCategory" type="hidden" name="PageCategory"></input>
```

to:

```
<input id="HiddenCategory" type="text" name="PageCategory" value="OTHER"></input>
```

?

Comment: inputs elements are self closing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$("#HiddenCategory").attr("type", "text").val("OTHER");
```

This is untested but i think it should work ok.

Comment: No probs.  Please mark this question as the correct one by clicking the tick

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie. Done. Thanks again